# How to count consecutively a sequence of number

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I need to SELECT and COUNT the amount of OrderIDs which have received a 10% discount.

I've tried using a COUNT function, but it only counts one unique entity occurrence and not for each of the OrderIDs.

```
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT a.OrderID, COUNT(a.OrderID) as 'SeqNo', b.ProductName, a.UnitPrice, a.Quantity, a.UnitPrice*a.Quantity as Amount, a.Discount
FROM [Order Details] as a
INNER JOIN [Products] as b
ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
GROUP BY a.OrderID, b.ProductName, a.UnitPrice, a.Quantity, a.Discount
HAVING a.Discount = 0.1
```

I actually want the 'SeqNo' to COUNT the OrderID but instead all of them are 1.

```
  OrderID SeqNo       ProductName      UnitPrice Quantity Amount Discount
1  10288  | 1  | Tourtiere             | 5.9    |  10 |   59.00  | 0.1
2  10288  | 2  | Scottish Longbreads   | 10     |  3  |   30.00  | 0.1
3  10291  | 1  | Konbu                 | 4.8    |  20 |   96.00  | 0.1
3  10291  | 2  | Gula Malacca          | 15.5   |  24 |   372.00 | 0.1
3  10291  | 3  | Mankimup Dried Apples | 42.4   |  2  |   84.8   | 0.1
```

Comment: You are using the group by with 5 different columns so it will check against the table for finding the duplicate (combination of 5 columns that mentioned in the group By). That said, it will returns all records as you have shown above. If you want the count then you should group by with order ID and sum the unit price and quantity accordingly so it will give you proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `row_number()` function with `partition by` and `order by` parts as

```
row_number() over (partition by OrderID  order by OrderID ) as SeqNo
```

to start from `1` for each counting of distinct `OrderID`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `COUNT` for that matter :

```sql
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT a.OrderID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.OrderID ASC) AS 'SeqNo'
, b.ProductName
, a.UnitPrice
, a.Quantity
, a.UnitPrice*a.Quantity as Amount
, a.Discount
FROM [Order Details] as a
INNER JOIN [Products] as b
ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
GROUP BY a.OrderID, b.ProductName, a.UnitPrice, a.Quantity, a.Discount
HAVING a.Discount = 0.1
```

Read more about `ROW_NUMBER` : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

do you need Count Distinct Orders?

```
select Count(distinct OrderID) from [Order Details] where Discount=0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of such discounts per order, then you want:

```
SELECT od.OrderID, COUNT(*) as num_discounts
FROM [Order Details] od
WHERE od.Discount = 0.1
GROUP BY od.OrderID;
```

If you want the number of orders with such a discount on any orderline:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT od.OrderID)
FROM [Order Details] od
WHERE od.Discount = 0.1;
```

I am not sure why you have included other columns in the `SELECT` to answer this question.